# Add value of column of even rows to odd rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame in Python that looks something like this:

[image]

I want to add the values of col2 of the even rows (alpha2 and beta2) to the corresponding odd rows (alpha and beta). Consequently, I want to remove the even rows in order to obtain the following DataFrame:

[image]

My code (that adds the values) currently looks like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 2):
    df.loc[df.index[i], 'col2'] += df.loc[df.index[i+1], 'col2']
```

Is there a more clever way to do this?

Comment: Try this? `df.groupby(df.index // 2).col2.sum()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can perform a `groupby` and reassign the index -

```
v = df.groupby(df.index // 2).col2.sum()
v.index = df.col1[::2]
v.reset_index()

    col1  col2
0  alpha    30
1   beta    70
```

Courtesy MaxU, a better way to do this would be passing `np.arange` to `groupby` -

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2).col2.sum()
```

---

**Option 2**
Another way to do this is to slice and assign -

```
y = df.col2.values
v = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : df.col1.values[::2], 'col2' : y[::2] + y[1::2]})
v

    col1  col2
0  alpha    30
1   beta    70
```

Comment: `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2).col2.sum()` - is robuster, because it'll work also with non-numeric indices...